# Should I migrate to Manifest v3 because most of the features of my extension depends on persistent background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome extension which uses WebSocket, webrtc, audio and HTTP connections heavily, also I am using react-redux in the background to keep a state of UI in the background for persisting current users' UI state. Now in Manifest v3, google removed the background and moved to the service worker, which is not feasible for making Websocket, webrtc connections, playing audio and storing redux state because it can terminate at any time and destroy all. There are multiple workarounds to fix all the problems but no solid solutions are there.

Please guide me should I continue with the migration to MV3 with these alternative solutions or just get out of the chrome extension and create a desktop app.

Comment: well, MV2 will eventually stop working, won't it? so, yes, continue the migratory process

Comment: ManifestV3 may add [offscreen document](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/170) to implement the missing features in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, they will probably delay the transition until V3 becomes better. The extensions with the most downloads (as far as I can see) all still use V2. Even Google's own extensions still use V2.

If they don't delay it and don't fix any of the major issues you could consider Firefox or a desktop app. I don't think having to use weird solutions all the time to adjust to Chrome's extension nerfs is fun in the long run.